# How do I search for a tag across all Stack Overflow networks?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Case in point: I want to ask a question about KissMetrics (kissmetrics.com - a website analytics service), and don't have an hour to read and figure out what network the question belongs in. I know that the network in question probably has a [kissmetrics] tag for it, and for narrowing down to good candidates, it would be helpful to have a view where I can search for tags, immediately filter out all networks that don't have that tag, and see the breakdown by tag activity across the rest, with more in-depth notes about each network, so I'll know if it's on topic asking the type of question I had in mind or not.

Does this exist already? The closest I have found is https://stackexchange.com/search?q=kissmetrics but it doesn't give very good data.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=kissmetrics+site%3Astackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This won't give you the breakdown you want, but if you're going by tags, your best bet for following and discovering new questions is to set up a tag filter:

- Go to https://stackexchange.com/filters/
- Sign in if you need to
- Click "New Filter" in the right sidebar
- Add the tag names you want to follow and click "Add Rule"
- Give your filter a name and then hit "Save Changes"

(That being said, it doesn't look like any site right now has a "kissmetrics" tag.)

---

Now, on to figuring out where you can ask a question... posting here on meta with a [site-rec](/questions/tagged/site-rec) tag is what most people do. Give some details about the question you want to ask and someone will recommend an appropriate site. :)

Comment: Thanks! I actually took a wild guess posting it at http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/38295/how-do-i-get-the-time-yyyy-mm-dd-hhmmss-of-my-kissmetrics-events/38345 despite the lack of that tag; that service is probably just less commonly used than I thought.

Comment: @ecmanaut Webmasters sounds like a good choice. :)