# Unify tag "nearest-neighbor" across different SE sites

Tags: discussion, tags

For example, Stackoverflow has tags [nearest-neighbor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nearest-neighbor) and [knn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/knn);
stats.stackexchange has
[k-nearest-neighbo**U**r](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/k-nearest-neighbour)
-- British spelling.
How could these be unified -- "nearest-neighbor" + synonyms ?

A related question from 2012 is 
[How do I search for a tag across all Stack Overflow networks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156777/how-do-i-search-for-a-tag-across-all-stack-overflow-networks)
Today's method is
http://google.com/search?q=nearest-neighbor+site:stackexchange.com.

Comment: So, why should tags from completely different sites, with completely different scopes be unified (spelling or otherwise)?

Comment: OK, title changed. Would any of the downvoters agree that *some* tags should be unified ?

Comment: Personally, I don't agree. Different sites, different tags. No relation. Should the DIY site table tag be unified with the DBA site table tag?

Comment: Nearest neighbor causes some [tagging confusion](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/q/4094/115) at [gis.se] too because it gets used in at least two ways there. I think tagging decisions are best sorted out within communities rather than enforced between sites.  Perhaps you can join each site that uses it and participate in its Meta.

Comment: @Oded for sites with migration paths, if there isn't a matching tag the migration is rejected. This either means synchronizing the spellings or making it so that the destination has an synonym.

Comment: @PolyGeo, could you follow up on this ? I agree on communities (was suggesting more helpful tagging, not enforcement), but am not about to ask for -10 on each Meta. Thanks

Comment: It's not a discussion that I am keen to get more involved in than the original answer I gave at [Meta GIS SE](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4094/nearest-neighbour-and-confusion-with-some-synonymous-tags).  I'm leaving it to its community to discuss further but consensus seems to have stagnated.

Answer (score 4):

There is actually no SE wide policy on naming tags, so that makes enforcing a specific language to use (US English vs. British English) hard, if not impossible, not to speak about the language-specific sites which don't even use English but Portugese for example, which has the same spelling problem.

Besides that, I think it is not really an issue that should be fixed.

Every community / site is responsible for their own tags, and that works fine. No need to unify tags across the SE network. Google usually does a pretty good job in joining the results anyway, so that isn't really a problem too.

Comment: "works fine": for experts, but not for beginners. "Nearest neighbor" straddles stackoverlow, stats, datascience ... A recent question on stats had many good answers on SO and datascience.  Easier search across stack* would give us more users, happier users.

Answer (score 0):

On sites that have a need for it, tag synonyms are created for British - American words.

**On sites that need it**

Which is definitely not all sites. And of course many sites have their own specific tags which aren't used on any other sites, or even more confusingly, have different meaning on different sites.

What I'm trying to say is: this actually couldn't work consistently. Some tags would break badly, and basically this would leave us with unhappy communities and a broken user experience.